# Get the split list Average in python

Tags: python, list

**My Code**

```
data = input("Enter your numbers: ").split(", ")

print("list: ", data)

q =  sum(data)

print("Sum: ", q)
```

**Input**

```
7,45,78,3
```

**Output**

```
 ['7,45,78,3']
```

**Traceback**

the error is in line 3 (`q =  sum(data)`) and it says :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I can not go farther to get Average . what should I do now ?

Comment: Your values are strings; you need to convert them to integers (or floats) to add them.

Comment: Besides the number conversion there is an additional problem. Please check the difference between `'7,45,78,3'.split(', ')` and `'7,45,78,3'.split(',')`.

Comment: @Nick would U tell me how should i do that?

Comment: @TheEpic looks like you have an answer...

Answer (score -1):

to get avg, you need to convert each input to int value. currentl all no are in string format

```
data = input("Enter your numbers: ").split(", ")
data= [int(i) for i in data]
print("list: ", data)

q =  sum(data)

print("Sum: ", q)
```

Comment: A quicker way to get the input: ```data = list(map(int, input("Enter nums: ").split(", ")))``` Then you don't need the second line.

Comment: @SaladHead yes, but i think it will be more clearer to OP if i write this way